# How do I do SEO for multiple search keywords that are similar but not the same

Tags: seo, google, keywords

For example:
I have an article about seo for urls.

People may search for

- seo for urls
- seo urls in google
- seo url panda update google

I want them to rank well for all of these search keywords. What strategy should I use so I return high on as many of these keywords as possible?

Comment: I love the irony of asking for SEO advice for an article about SEO ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and there are many ways to solve you question.  When building a webpage or website with SEO in mind you have to remember there are many indicators.  So you can use these indicators to show slightly different version of what you are talking about.

For example you could:

- Make your title "SEO for URLs"
- Make your H1 tag "SEO URLS in Google"
- Include in your text the words seo, url, panda, update and google all within close proximity of each other.

Look for important words, like SEO in this case and try to reuse those words more often and in more combinations.  Also, make sure you put the most popular keywords into the best SEO  ranking factor areas.

Take a look at SEOMoz's Key Ranking Factors, http://www.seomoz.org/article/search-ranking-factors, to get a good idea what the key factors are and how you can help yourself the most.

Comment: thanks, however, using "Include in your text the words seo, url, panda, update and google all within close proximity of each other" I may not rank good for users searching with "seo url panda update google".......

Comment: @Jeet - On any webpage there is a limit to the number of SERPs that will return it on the first, or any page for that matter.  They key is to do research on sites like Google's Keyword tool to see how many people search a keyword.  For instance, the keyword "seo url panda update google" had 0 searches in the world in the last month so there is no reason to optimize for it.  When you look at your keywords you need to prioritize based on what has been searched the most in the past unless you have a hint as to a new keyword becoming more popular in the near future.